# Detect user like specific facebook pages doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried the old Facebook API method, it deprecated and won't work anymore. Right now I'm used /me/likes/{page-id} to retrieve whether my facebook account likes this page or not. I need to detect users are liking all the fan pages before specific action is taken.

```
FB.api("me/likes/184522495376661", function(response) {
 if ( response.data.length === 1 ) {
     FB.api("me/likes/1125511580839629", function(response) {
       if ( response.data.length === 1 ) { 
           FB.api("me/likes/1603408753260758", function(response) {
             if ( response.data.length === 1 ) { 
                  // Specific action takes place here
             } else {
                 alert("You haven't like third page!");
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
             }
           });
       } else {
           alert("You haven't like second page!");
           console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
       }
    });
  } else {
     alert("You haven't like our first page!");
     console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
});
```

Each user required Facebook Login before detect the page likes.

```
FB.login(function (response) {
  if (response.status === "connected") {
     var uID = response.authResponse.userID;
     fb_id = uID;
  }else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
  }
},{ scope: 'email,user_likes,public_profile' });
```

The above codes work for my personal facebook account. But when it comes to other facebook id, the `me/likes/{page-id}` returns null, but that particular Facebook account already like the page, the API doesn't detect.

Comment: Why would you need to know if they liked all the pages? Like gating is not allowed

Comment: @WizKid To make sure they like all three FB pages before they can perform the specific action.

Comment: Which is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: Like Gating is not allowed any more. You are not allowed to present users with different content based on whether they liked specific pages or not. And Facebook will not approve your app’s use of the necessary permission for such a purpose in review.